# How do I change keyboard shortcuts in Nautilus 3.4

Tags: nautilus

I am using Nautilus 3.4 and xubuntu 12.04. I know in Nautilus 3.6 the keyboard shortcuts can be changed in `~/.config/nautilus/accels`, however in 3.4 that file does not exist. Is there another file in version 3.4 that I can use to edit the keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've figured it out:

The keyboard shortcuts are in `~/.gnome/accels/nautilus`.

The shortcuts appear like this:

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/TabsMoveRight" "<Primary><Shift>Page_Down")
```

To change a shortcut, modify the final quote section to the keyboard shortcut you want, and then remove the semicolon at the beginning. For example, if you wanted to change the above shortcut from `Ctrl + Shift + Page-Down` to `Ctrl + Shift + Right`, then change the above line to:

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/TabsMoveRight" "<Primary><Shift>Right")
```

Comment: Nautilus 3.22 has no such file.