# how to change system shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys

default shortcut key for copy is ctrl + c but it is'nt good enough while typing fast. I think it's better to be alt + c. 
in keyboard setting , there isn't shortcut for copy or paste. 
how should I change it on ubuntu 15 ? 
also I should use fn + f12 to louder the sound , and it's a very bad short cut . because of the distance between them. 
how can I change the sound key?

Answer (score 0):

For changing the sound key:

1. System settings
2. Keyboard
3. Shortcuts
4. Sound and media
5. Type on the Ctrl +F12 next to Volume up and edit the shortcut

As for the copy shortcut, it should be fixed to each application separately. There is no systemwide shortcut for this.

Comment: thanks...    I want copy shortcut in file explorer to copy files with alt + c .. :)

Comment: See here for Nautilus shortcuts: http://askubuntu.com/questions/389072/how-do-i-change-keyboard-shortcuts-in-nautilus-3-4